# Cannot create assoication between new objects for nested model form in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am watching on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast) and tried to write the example with my own hands.
But I got an trouble with the step of: Creating The Form.

It requires creating association between Survey and Question.
But this association cannot be established in my rails application so no questions appear in the form

Here are the codes

**Survey model:**

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :questions
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions

end
```

**Question model:**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :context, :survey_id
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

**Surveys_Controller method:**

```
  # GET /surveys/new
  # GET /surveys/new.json
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times {@survey.questions.build}


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @survey }
    end
  end
```

**question part in _form.html.erb**

```
  <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder|%>
    <%= builder.label :context, "Question" %><br />
    <%= builder.text_area :context, :rows => 3 %>
  <% end %>
```

**Here is what I got from testing in console**

```
irb(main):010:0> @survey = Survey.new
=> #<Survey id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):011:0> 3.times {@survey.questions.build}
=> 3
irb(main):012:0> @survey.questions
=> [#<Question id: nil, survey_id: nil, context: nil, created_at: nil, updated_a
t: nil>, #<Question id: nil, survey_id: nil, context: nil, created_at: nil, upda
ted_at: nil>, #<Question id: nil, survey_id: nil, context: nil, created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>]
```

Comment: This might be an aside from your problem, but I noticed that your `attr_accessible` values contains `:questions`. For nested attributes, this should be `:questions_attributes` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You are right, man. It is used with mass_assignment. I fixed this problem but thank for your notice :) But I wonder if there is any security problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha, i am being stupid.
It is a dumb question.
It doesn't matter about the association.

I made a typing mistake on

`<%` `f.fields_for :questions do |builder|%>`

it should return some texts inserting into HTML document rather than just processing as ruby code

it should be `<%=` `f.fields_for :questions do |builder|%>`

But thank you all of your answers  :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a new object for model. You create 3 question for empty object. You questions must be empty. It no saved or defined.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are not seeing questions in your form. You need to have one form for one question in your form. Are you doing questions.each in your form?

You need something like:

```
<% survey.questions.each do |question| %>
      <%= fields_for question do |builder| %>
```